# How to use std::indirect_result_t in C++20

Tags: c++, types, c++20

[`std::indirect_result_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/indirect_result_t) is introduced in C++20 and I am wondering how to use `std::indirect_result_t` correctly. Could someone give an example usage of it?

Comment: It is to work with "iterators"/pointer, so roughly `declltype(f(*it, *it2))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use it to name the result type of dereferencing a pack of arguments into a callable.

Given a callable `f` of type `F`, and indirect arguments `is...` of types `Is...`, `std::indirect_result_t<F, Is...>` is equal to `decltype(f(*is...))`